# Check if a array is contained in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

Im struggling with a piece of code i have below and cant seam to find something like it anywhere on stacks.

I have tried using the JavaScript .indexof(is returning all that doesn't contain variables) as well as the .match(shows all even if contain part of the word. i need it to be exact for obvious reasons) and even jquery.

I was wondering if anyone can help me.

I have a script that pulls data from the server into the following array.

from there i need to be able to compare this array with data that is on the page. if it exists in the server i want to highlight the checkbox i have created. when i did .match it found all variables that contained say the characters foo but i need exact matches not just if it contains.

see below for what i currently have. (note that the variables aren't set in stone and some may be different that will be contained in others which is why they need to be exact)

```js
var industriesget = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental Issues", "Hotels & Tourism"];
var industries = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental Issues", "Hotels & Tourism", "Liquor, Wine & Beer", "Defense Industries", "Publishing & Printing", "Real Estate", "Not For Profit", "Food Services", "Corporate & Banking", "Agriculture & Fishing", "Communications", "Manufacturing", "Mining", "Entertainment & Gambling", "Retail Sales", "Signage & Fitouts", "Construction", "Transportation", "Public Utilities", "Education" ];

for ( var i = 0; i < industries.length; i++ ) {
//another for loop to run through the matches?
if..........
  document.write( "<label for='" + industries[ i ] + "' class='col-md-2 col-xs-5' style=' float:left; height:55px;' valign='middle'>" + industries[ i ] + "<input valign='middle' type='checkbox' style='vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;' name='products' id='" + industries[ i ] + "' checked></label>" );
  
 else{
 document.write( "<label for='" + industries[ i ] + "' class='col-md-2 col-xs-5' style=' float:left; height:55px;' valign='middle'>" + industries[ i ] + "<input valign='middle' type='checkbox' style='vertical-align: middle;text-
 }
 
 
}
```

Comment: check using `typeof`

Comment: share the code where you have done comparison

Comment: `if (industriesget.includes(industries[ i ]))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? This is simplest way.

```js
var industriesget = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental Issues", "Hotels & Tourism"];
var industries = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental Issues", "Hotels & Tourism", "Liquor, Wine & Beer", "Defense Industries", "Publishing & Printing", "Real Estate", "Not For Profit", "Food Services", "Corporate & Banking", "Agriculture & Fishing", "Communications", "Manufacturing", "Mining", "Entertainment & Gambling", "Retail Sales", "Signage & Fitouts", "Construction", "Transportation", "Public Utilities", "Education" ];




for ( var i = 0; i < industries.length; i++ ) {
//another for loop to run through the matches?
if(industriesget.indexOf(industries[i])!== -1)
  document.write( "<label for='" + industries[ i ] + "' class='col-md-2 col-xs-5' style=' float:left; height:55px;' valign='middle'>" + industries[ i ] + "<input valign='middle' type='checkbox' style='vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;' name='products' id='" + industries[ i ] + "' checked></label>" );
  
 else{
 document.write( "<label for='" + industries[ i ] + "' class='col-md-2 col-xs-5' style=' float:left; height:55px;' valign='middle'>" + industries[ i ] + "<input valign='middle' type='checkbox' style='vertical-align: middle;text-")
 }
 
 
}
```

If you want to find whether industriesget is subset of industries, then try using

```
var intersectionIndustries = industries.filter(function(n) {
    return industriesget.indexOf(n) !== -1;
});
```

and check

```
(intersectionIndustries.length == industriesget.length)
```

,if true then its subset, else there are non existent entries in industries get.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
pass two arrays to this function and check if the flag is true or not:

```
        var industriesget = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental 
         Issues", "Hotels & Tourism"];
        var industries = [ "Servers & Software", "Environmental Issues", "Hotels 
       & Tourism", "Liquor, Wine & Beer", "Defense Industries", "Publishing & 
       Printing", "Real Estate", "Not For Profit", "Food Services", "Corporate & 
       Banking", "Agriculture & Fishing", "Communications", "Manufacturing", 
       "Mining", "Entertainment & Gambling", "Retail Sales", "Signage & 
      Fitouts", 
      "Construction", "Transportation", "Public Utilities", "Education" ];

        if(arr(industriesget,industries)) {
            alert("contains");
        }
```

Where our function is:

```
function arr(industriesget,industries)
 {
   var flag=false;
    for(var i=0;i<industriesget.length;i++)
     {
        if(industries.includes(industriesget[i])) {           
           flag = true; 
        }
     }
return flag;
}
```